# Allow internet access via http

Tags: android, android-studio, http, android-manifest

**My question:** How to allow internet access via http in android studio? I've googled this for a while but i can't find a working answer. I've tried to add **that** to my manifest, but `D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default` still is showing up when i run the game:

Tried **that:**

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">`

Does anybody know what I might be missing? I'm thankful for any help! :)

PS: I created the game in Unity and exported it to android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create xml under res directory and then network_security_config.xml in XML folder
and put in xml file this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

and add this line to your application tag in manifest

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

i hope solve your problem...